# System Warning while application is launching

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

I know that there is two ways to launch application from terminal on Mac OS:

1. /User/username/Applications/Appname.app/Contents/MacOS/Appname
2. open /User/username/Applications/Appname.app

The difference between these ways is that in the second case system shows System Warning message if application was downloaded from the Internet.

Second case is good for me and it has same behavior like when user open the application by clicking on app icon. But this take to much time (25-30 seconds) from open application till System Warning message shows. If open application like in the first case it will open in one second.

Why this take so much time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for my own question: `open -a Finder /User/username/Applications/Appname.app`